# What RSS Reader can handle item-updating (JIRA search) feeds?

Tags: rss, feed-reader, jira

Thunderbird is a good rss reader in terms of being able to connect successfully to jira authenticated search feeds (where evolution-rss and Liferea can't), but really sucks when it comes to updating.

A Jira search feed will give a link id to `http://jira/browse/[ticket no]`, and if that ticket/feed-item is updated, thunderbird refuses to update it - it already has it! (even though the item date does not match).
Also, if you delete the ticket update, it will never show up again for that news account.

Has anybody found an RSS reader that can work with JIRA/updating RSS items?

***Note:** this is not the same as Jira activity feeds - those work great, as each update has a unique item id*

To replicate:

1. Grab a search (any search)
2. Get it into your rss reader
3. Read an item, modify the linked ticket
4. Update rss and see if the ticket bumps to most recent and unread

*or,* generically:

1. Get an rss feed (from your hard drive?)
2. Modify an item in the middle changing the content, the date, and moving it to the top
3. Update rss and see if the ticket bumps to most recent and unread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Great News](http://www.curiostudio.com/index.html).

This item in their changelog sounds a lot like what you want:

> GreatNews 1.0 Beta (Build 376)
> Released on 11/27/2006
>
> Added: Option to decide marking
> changed article unread or not (Default
> is off)
> Tools->Options->Usability->Mark
> Changed Item UnreadChanged Item Unread

I don't know if it'll give you trouble connecting to an authenticated feed, but it's worth a shot.

Of course, [the ideal solution](http://www.feedreader.com/node/1494) would be for Jira to produce feeds that treat every change like a new item. If you can get the Jira administrator to make the following source code modification, things should improve for all users.

> Submitted by Leanid on Wed, 2008-03-26 15:04.
>
> I kinda find workaround.
>
> I added timestamp in Jira RSS generation to .
>
> For thouse who interested change file:
>
> atlassian-jira\WEB-INF\classes\templates\plugins\searchrequestviews\searchrequest-rss.vm
>
> Chnage line:
>
> #esc($requestContext.baseUrl)/browse/$issue.key
>
> to
>
> #esc($requestContext.baseUrl)/browse/$issue.key$outlookdate.formatRssRfc822($issue.updated)